# How do I set the SCM tag in the Maven Release Plugin?

Tags: maven, version-control, maven-release-plugin

When I run the `release:prepare` Maven goal it asks me for the version three times: release, release, next-snapshot.

Is it possible to force the second one to be always like the first one?

```
What is the release version for "app1"? (org.dep1:app1) 1.0.9: : 
What is the SCM release tag or label for "app1"? (org.dep1:app1) 1.0.9: : 
What is the new development version for "app1"? (org.dep1:app1) 1.0.10-SNAPSHOT: :
```

I would prefer to always have the git tag identical to the version number, and ideally skip the second question.

Here's my Maven Release Plugin configuration:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-M1</version>
    <configuration>
      <tagNameFormat>@{project.version}</tagNameFormat>
      <autoVersionSubmodules>true</autoVersionSubmodules>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Comment: You could use `mvn -B release:prepare release:perform`...

Comment: @khmarbaise The batch option could be useful for the first question, but the last one could be different. In this case it could respond like `1.1.0-SNAPSHOT`. However, the default value could still be good, and the developers can change it later. Thanks

Comment: @khmarbaise After thinking more about it I think your solution is what I actually need. If I need a different SNAPSHOT version, I can change it (including all five submodules) using `mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=1.2.0-SNAPSHOT`. Please add the answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest step is to use batch mode which can be done like this:

```
mvn -B release:prepare release:perform
```

This will use the defaults without asking for anything.

If you want to set the [releaseVersion](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/prepare-mojo.html) you can do that via:

```
mvn -B release:prepare release:perform -DreleaseVersion=2.0.0
```

To control which [development version](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/prepare-mojo.html) will be used you can set this by adding`-D developmentVersion=2.1.0-SNAPSHOT` if you don't like the default.